# Multiple tar archives w/ specific amount of files each

Tags: 16.04, tar, archive

I have a folder containing 20,000 jpg files. My goal is to create 5 tar archives containing 4000 files each.

How can I do that using standard tools such as find,tar, etc? Or via bash?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `find`, `sort`, `xargs`, and let you make the `.tar` file names unique on your own. Read the `man` pages for each, and here we go:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 | \
sort -z | \
xargs -0 --max-args=4000 echo tar cf FIXME.tar >doit.tmp
# now, edit (`nano`, `vim`, `emacs`) the `doit.tmp` file, 
# replacing `FIXME` with 4 unique names, then
. ./doit.tmp
```